# Purchasing mp3 files from ebay

Tags: contemporary-halacha

Wondering if anyone knows the halacha regarding purchasing mp3 files from ebay which may be potential copyright violations?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.356.1

Comment: @doubleaa -- This does not explain how to handle uncertainty, which I take to be the heart of the question.  How do you know if something you buy is stolen?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi That's fine, but then let's just close this as a duplicate of the general question of if pirated content is stealing. We don't need that discussion repeated in two places

Comment: This is not known to be pirated.  That is the issue.  It may legitamate and according to us law one may resell digital content he owns,  Please send a link to the discussion elsewhere.  Tks.